# Determine if the following arithmetics are sentences

Tags: logic, arithmetic

How would you determine if these arithmetics are sentences or not?

```
-(x + 2) > y
i++ == 2
i++ == 2 is this sentence True where i = 1
```

I understand it as if the expression can be determinated as true/false, and there are no free variables, it is a sentence. But in my mind only the last one is a sentence since the variable i is bounded to be 1 and the expression can be true/false, whereas the other do not really have an limitation on their variables.

Answer (score 1):

According to ref [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Free_and_bound_variables):

> A formula in first-order logic with no free variable occurrences is called a first-order sentence. These are the formulas that will have well-defined truth values under an interpretation.

So only $\exists i. i++ == 2$ is a sentence (closed formula), otherwise is (open) formula. And unlike most programming languages, in logic with identity we normally just use $=$ as identity relation symbol in the alphabet and we add functional symbols if needed to express functions such as ++ in your case...